# Call Individual Index of WebElement List

Tags: java, selenium

If anyone needs reference or background here was my first question asked

[Retrieving a list of WebElements and Identifying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186674/retrieving-a-list-of-webelements-and-identifying-them/36305024#36305024)

At this point I have retrieved a list of WebElements

```
@FindBy(css =   "td[id^=ctl00_SomeGridData_ucControlList_trgControlList_ctl00__]")
List<WebElement> allGridData;
```

At this point in my code I can use the web Element to call the index for example

```
allGridData.get(0).click
```

however the list is not strictly integers for example if I access at the row level `<tr>` it would be:

```
ctl00_SomeGridData_ucControlList_trgControlList_ctl00__0
```

but if I were to call a link within row they are table data `<td>` broken into divs that look like this:

```
ctl00_SomeGridData_ucControlList_trgControlList_ctl00__ctl04_lbView
ctl00_SomeGridData_ucControlList_trgControlList_ctl00__ctl04_hlTestPlan
```

or this

```
ctl00_SomeGridData_ucControlList_trgControlList_ctl00__ctl07_lbView
ctl00_SomeGridData_ucControlList_trgControlList_ctl00__ctl07_hlTestPlan
```

Since all the WebElements start with a common css selector

```
  @FindBy(css =     "td[id^=ctl00_SomeGridData_ucControlList_trgControlList_ctl00__]")
    List<WebElement> allGridData;
```

how can identify a specific index that is a char value (ie ctl107) vs just an integer?

Comment: Could you post the HTML code that you are working with? Would make things clear.

Comment: Updated in the top portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want two lists, one for the View Details and one for the View Test Plans, you need the `$` (ends with):

```
@FindBy(css = "a[id$=lbView]")
List<WebElement> allDetailViewLinks;

@FindBy(css = "a[id$=hlTestPlan]")
List<WebElement> allTestPlanLinks;
```

But my best guess is that you want to click on a link in a specific row rather than based on index in a list of Web Elements. For instance based on the text in the `td` in  `<tr id="ctl00_SoxMain_ucControlList_trgControlList_ctl00__0" class="rgRow">
<td class="rgExpandCol" valign="top"/><td valign="top">AL-01</td>`.

You need a method to get the row with specific text in the td.

```
WebElement getRow(String specificValue) {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='"+specificValue+"']"))
           .findElement(By.xpath(".."));
}
```

Then you can make the methods for detail view and test plan view.

```
public void openDetailsView(String specificValue) {
    getRow(specificValue)
        .findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id$=lbView]"))
        .click();
}

public void openTestPlanView(String specificValue) {
    getRow(specificValue)
        .findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id$=hlTestPlan]"))
        .click();
}
```

Comment: Great thank you for the detailed explanation! I will get this implemented.